# How to Fix the problem of No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in a SpringBoot+Vuejs app build with Gradle plugin

Tags: java, spring-boot, vue.js, spring-security, cors

in this app im doing when i work in local with a h2-embeded database , the problem doesnt shows up, and only appears once i deploy to heroku and create a Postgresql database which use all the data from h2.
Literall y the app doesnt recognize the headers brought form the request , throwing as respopnse

```
Access to fetch at 'https://xxxxxx.herokuapp.com/bikes/all' from origin 'http://localhost:8082'
 has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the 
requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors'
 to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

The dependencies used for spring are:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    //runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql") 
......
```

and in my app properties in order to connect with that database once is deployed to Heroku , i initialize this:

```
### ----- COMMENT THIS PART TO WORK IN LOCAL! FROM HERE... -----
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD}
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Then on my application class , i do enable all referring to web security included the allowed origins which i declared as (*)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(inputName-> {
            User user = userRepository.findByUserName(inputName);
            if (user != null) {
                return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUserName(), user.getUserPassword(),
                        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("USER"));
            } else {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Unknown user: " + inputName);
            }
        });
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors();///de heroku tambien
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/bikes/all").permitAll()
                                .antMatchers("/bikes/user/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/rest/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/**").hasAuthority("USER")
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
        
        http.formLogin()
                .usernameParameter("name")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .loginPage("/bikes/login");
        http.logout().logoutUrl("/api/logout");
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint((req, res, exc) -> res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED));
        http.formLogin().successHandler((req, res, auth) -> clearAuthenticationAttributes(req));
        http.formLogin().failureHandler((req, res, exc) -> res.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED));
        http.logout().logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler());
        http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
    }

    private void clearAuthenticationAttributes(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            session.removeAttribute(WebAttributes.AUTHENTICATION_EXCEPTION);
        }
    }
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD",
                "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

Even as alternative isntead of (*), i specified the exact origin might be allowed , iin this case

```
http://localhost:8082(cause im doing the request of my front from local)
```

But neither works

In my front end calling the action , either put the header specifying the origing allowed (*), or localhot :8082, or even none , and still the error persists

```
const url=xxxxxxxxx.herokuapp.com/

fetchAllBikesJson({ commit}) {
       fetch(url +"bikes/all", {
         credentials: "include",
        
Option1
         headers: {
           "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
         },
Option 2
         headers: {
           "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:8082"
         },
Option 2
         NO HEADERS
        method: "GET",
      })
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((response) => {
          // console.log(response);
          response;
          commit("setAllBikesJson", response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // console.log("error", error);
          error;
        });
    },
```

Also adding a view for the error from my wen console as well as one from my web console in the Network item

[image]

[image]
Any help about about his issue .thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: Check your web console, do you see `OPTIONS` Request before GET?

Comment: no options after it ,chech the image @code_mechanic

Answer (score 2):

Try defining the configuration instead of bean cors configuration

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
      .allowedOrigins("*")
      .allowedMethods("HEAD", "GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS");
  }
}
```

Also I noticed that you have in your code like this:

```
http.cors();
....
...http.etc()

Instead it should be http.cors().and() // May be this is your issue
```

Please check [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/cors.html)

Comment: Your welcome @EnriqueGF, glad it solved your problem

Comment: Well still keeps on the same mistake , applied some concepts you suggest me to , but still the error is present.Just really thanks for your help

Comment: but now it varies to

Comment: "esponse to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: Add `OPTIONS` to your allowed methods. I have edited my answer.